# Submit a JSON.stringify created with javascript to a page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In my page I have a jquery plugin that create a variable `result` created with this rule:

```
var result = JSON.stringify(params, null, 2)
```

where `params` is (from Firefox console): `Array [ "test" ]`

So `result` became:

```
[
  "test"
]
```

Then I append it to form before submit:

```
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="result" value="' + result + '">');
```

In the PHP destination page if I try to `var_dump($_POST['result'])` I get always `NULL`

Probably is not a valid JSON?

I tried also this:

```
 form.append('<input type="hidden" name="result" value="' + encodeURIComponent(result) + '">');
```

with

```
 var_dump(json_decode($_POST['result']))
```

but still not get a valid array to PHP page

Comment: Quotes are messed up because you're making the element into a big messy string with the value inside it.  I suggest you create the element in step 1 and then set its value as step 2 to avoid having to figure out how to encode all the quotes.

Comment: Do you still receive NULL after change to `encodeURIComponent(result)`?

Answer (score 0):

If in `params` you have just normal Array, this can help you:

```
params.forEach((val) => {
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="' + val +'">');
});
```

You will have few hidden `<input>`s and be able receive them as an array on the server side.

**Note.** Here I'm using "arrow function" syntax, adapt your code to following if needed:

```
params.forEach(function(val) {
    form.append('<input type="text" name="result[]" value="' + val +'">');
});
```